# IF function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want the create the following:
If a cell in column C contains the value TRUE, the corresponding value in column B should be copied to the corresponding cell in column AJ.

This is what I have so far:

```
Range("AJ2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(C[-33]=TRUE,B:B,0)"
Range("AJ2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AJ2:AJ1324")
```

The problem occurs when I run the macro. The following statement is copied in the cells in column AJ:
`=IF(C:C=TRUE;B:(B);0)`, 
where I expect the following:

```
=IF(C:C=TRUE;B:B;0)
```

Could someone, please, tell me where my mistake is?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean `=IF(C2=TRUE;B2;0)` (copied down to row 1324)?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(C[-33]=TRUE,RC2,0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing R1C1 and A1 type references in the formula. `B:B` is not an R1C1 reference.

If you want:

```
=IF(C:C=TRUE;B:B;0)
```

Then you need to use:

```
"=IF(C[-33]=TRUE,C[-34],0)"
```

I suspect that may not be the formula you really want, but you have not addressed that issue.

One method of obtaining the correct formula is to enter what you really want into the cell, then examine the cell.FormulaR1C1 property to see how that formula is formed in the different notation.

I suspect, from your description, that what you really want would be created by:

```
"=IF(RC[-33]=TRUE,RC[-34],0)"
```

which would show, in the cell, as:

```
=IF(C2=TRUE;B2;0)
```

or

```
"=IF(RC3=TRUE,RC2,0)"
```

producing

```
=IF($C2=TRUE;$B2;0)
```